# Why does converting from a size_t to an unsigned int give me a warning?

Tags: c++, size-t

I have the code:

```
unsigned int length = strlen(somestring);
```

I'm compiling with the warning level on 4, and it's telling me that "conversion from `size_t` to `unsigned int`, possible loss of data" when a `size_t` is a `typedef` for an `unsigned int`.

Why!?

Edit:

I just solved my own problem. I'm an XP user, and my compiler was checking for 64 bit compatibility. Since `size_t` is platform dependent, for 64 bit it would be an `unsigned long long`, where that is not the same as an `unsigned int`.

Comment: All sizes are dependent. `size_t` doesn't have to equal to any other type, they could all be different. The only guarantee you have is that `sizeof(char) == 1`, and that the number of bits in a `char` (which is also dependent!) is defined in the macro `CHAR_BIT` in the header `<climits>`, and that `sizeof(short) >= sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(long)`, and `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(long)`.

Comment: @GMan: Actually I believe `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)` :) +1 though

Comment: @Billy: Oh dangit. Now it's too late to fix. -_- Oh well. :3

Comment: And an `int` has to be at least 16 bits and a `long` at least 32 bits; that's specified in `limits.h` in the C89 standard, which also applies to C++03.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `unsigned int` is a narrower type on your machine than `size_t`. Most likely `size_t` is 64 bits wide, while `unsigned int` is 32 bits wide.

EDIT: size_t is not a typedef for unsigned int.

Comment: Well, `size_t` _is_ a typedef for `unsigned` on some systems.  It won't be on LP64 and LLP64 systems though.  :-)

Comment: @James McNellis: Maybe, but the standard doesn't define it that way :)